# Having trouble creating methods for objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

Okay,
I am trying to create an object in JavaScript. The project is a bit private so I blocked out the object name.

So I have created this objected, stated the constructor, but when I try to refer to the `someobject.t()` method, it will give an error saying that `someobject` has no method `t()`. I really have been raking over this for quite some time and I can't really see what I have done wrong. And have used this method of creating prototype object in JS before.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?


[image: This is a screenshot of my code.]

Comment: did you remember to create a new someobject?

Comment: yes, I have instantiated a `someobject`. and this code is implemented before I instantiated.

Comment: did you try simplifying it?  maybe just do `someobj.prototype.t = function(){...}`?

Comment: My eyes hurt trying to read that image.

Comment: @Jesse right-click "View Image"

Comment: @Moak: That helps, but pasting the code into the question would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops!
When I instantiated the object, I named it `runtime`, and I was trying to refer to the actual name.

Wrong:

```
function someObject(){
    this.bla = "cool";
}
runtime = new someObject();
var foo = someObject.bla; //This is wrong, you must refer to it as 'runtime'

/*LIKE THIS*/
var bar = runtime.bla; //bar now holds the string 'cool'
```